# Getting error for proxy in pycharm. Settings are applied but still coming

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, pycharm

I set my proxy setting in Pycharm. Tested connection successfully. But when I am trying to install some libraries it throw error 403. Please check the screenshot as the file is downloaded successfully, but after download completion. When Pycharm trying to "Installing build dependencies" it throws the following error:

```
"Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403
Forbidden',))': /packages/b2/86/095d2f7829badc207c893dd4ac767e871f6cd547145df797ea26baea4e2e/setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```

I set my proxy as `proxy.XYZ.com` but when its trying to connect I can see it is only proxy.

I already turned off the firewall security. Please refer the screenshot

Please suggest what will I do in this situation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWWYH.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably your Firewall is blocking connection!! Turn off your firewall and try even turning off antivirus

Comment: How to close firewall.? Since I am in office and I didn't have privileges to do that

Comment: I turned off the firewall in my system still the pycharm is not able to download libraries